Two definitions of a variety
$\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$
In my algebraic geometry course we defined a variety to be $k$-scheme $X$ which is of finite type, reduced, and separated over $\Spec k$. This definition seems to generally be in the spirit of the study of classical algebraic geometry where the objects of study are algebraic varieties.
However, in my course on Abelian Varieties we defined a variety to be a $k$-scheme $X$ which is of finite type, separated over $\Spec k$, and geometrically integral, in the sense that if $\bar k$ is the algebraic closure of $k$, then $X\times_k\Spec \bar{k}$ is an integral scheme.
Now the second definition seems to be much stronger than the former, and we used the fact that a variety was geometrically integral many many times throughout the course so it seemed that this was indeed a necessary condition to study abelian varieties (however, maybe it just made some proofs easier?).
The difference between these two definitions is confusing to me though, because of how much stronger the geometrically integral definition is. Indeed, I think $X$ has to be integral as if it wasn't then we could find an open affine $U=\Spec A\subset X$, which is not an integral domain. Then $\Spec A\otimes_k \bar{k}$ would be an open affine of the fibre product, and if $A$ is not an integral domain, then $A\otimes_k \bar{k}$ is. However, integral does not imply geometrically integral, because even if $A$ is an integral domain, then $A\otimes_k\bar{k}$ need not be an integral domain, so this not the same as just restricting to irreducible varieties.
Is there a good reason why one would take the latter as a definition for a variety?

It is exactly rigged up so the base change of a variety along an algebraic extension remains a variety. Your original definition doesn’t have that property! You could patch this by giving a third definition, namely “geometrically reduced.”

And the third definition which I am used to, is that a variety over $k$ is an integral separated scheme of finite type over $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$. There is a lot of variation

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641348/definition-of-algebraic-variety?rq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492560/what-is-an-algebraic-variety?rq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061538/equivalent-definitions-of-abelian-variety?rq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288814/integral-scheme-and-variety?rq=1

@FShrike to me thats just the case of reducing to irreducible varieties

@QiaochuYuan ok this is desirable, but why would we want to take this as the definition of a variety? Or I guess why haven’t we settled on a definition of a variety in the language of schemes?

Frankly I don't think this matters very much. There are a couple different things you might want to call a variety, and which one an author wants to study depends on what they're trying to do. I don't think there's much of a point in asking for some kind of universal context-free definition. I think everyone agrees that a variety should be reduced, separated, and of finite type; that's sort of a "maximal" definition. And I think everyone agrees that among these, the geometrically integral ones are definitely varieties; that's sort of a "minimal" definition. Between these there's room.
